# Using array functions in Rails model scope definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I am trying to use array functions (specifically, "keep_if" and "include?") within a scope (or self.func_name) for a Rails model, but don't know how to make it work. I was thinking it was possible because it seems like a "where" implies the "set.where", so a "set.keep_if" would make sense.

I have a table of documents (or, rather, the metadata for the documents), where each document has different versions of itself in the table, linked; doc.next_version and doc.prior_version. I have a table of people linked to the documents (via another table, 'author'), so person.documents is a list of all the versions of each document that person worked on. I want to get the first or last version of the document that each person worked on, rather than /every/ version.

Here was my guess as to the code:

```
class Document < ActiveRecorrd::Base

  has_many :authors

  belongs_to :next_version, :class_name => 'Document'
  has_one :prior_version, :class_name => 'Document'
  #document.document_id is the ID of the prior version of this document

  scope :last!, lambda{ keep_if{|d| (d.next_version.nil?)||(! include?(d.next_version))}}
  # Keep a doc if it either has no next_version (and is thus the last version in 
  # the database), or it's next version isn't in this list.
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
  has_many :documents, :through => :authors
end

class Author > ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :document
end

#Usage Example
documents = Person.find(id).documents.last!
published = documents.keep_if{|d| d.published}
success_rate = published.size / documents.size
# etc
```

I tried converting to a `self.first!`, but that didn't help. (I realize that if a person skips a version of a bill, this method won't skip, and will return two versions of that doc)

I'm looking to find out both more of what's going on within "scopes", and how to do what I'm trying to do, even if it uses a completely different method.

I have complete control over pretty much everything, although I'm generating the metadata from plain-text myself - so while I can probably add new metadata fields, I have to do all the work that entails.

Comment: It appears my guess as to how scopes work was totally off - they're named snippets of query, so I need to work out some queries to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - What's going on:

`scopes` function like named snippets of a query; you use them to build a query, and ActiveRecord lazily evaluates the resulting composite query. So, from the perspective of scopes and class methods, `Person.first.documents` *isn't* an array, even though it works like one from the perspective of other code - `Person.first.documents.keep_if{...}`

The work around is pretty simple - just prompt AREL to evaluate the query and turn into an array:

```
def self.last!
  all.keep_if{...}  
 #^^^ It's the "all" that does it
end
```

Note, my actual logic in this case, `(d.next_version.nil?)||(! all.include?(d.next_version))` doesn't work, and I'm not yet sure why.

Edit: It's something to do with 'belongs_to :next_version...', and a `def next_version` workaround gets things working, if not actually solving the problem.

Edit 2: I'm going to accept this as the answer for now, because it gets what I want done with the usage code the way I want, but IMO/AFAIK it's not a very Rails solution - so if you've got a better one, I'll totally jump ship to that one.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord already has a `last!` method, which you're overriding. I don't believe this is a good idea. Instead I think would be better to express your logic in a different way:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.published_documents
        keep_if do |d|
            (d.next_version.nil? || !include?(d.next_version)) && d.published
        end
    end
end
```

That implements the basic logic you're after IMO.

To go a step further, I think I'd also move this method to the Person class, since you're really interested in a Person's published documents:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

    def published_documents
        documents.keep_if do |d|
            (d.next_version.nil? || !documents.include?(d.next_version)) && d.published
        end
    end
end
```

Your usage then becomes:

```
Person.find(id).published_documents
```

Comment: The first code doesn't work and while the second one does, the point is to make Documents smarter so that any number of other relations can  use the smarts. You also haven't addressed the "what's going on here?" part of the question, just the specific case outlined. (Thanks for that, by the way, it's just not helping)